# Wordpress remove ::after with function.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i have a parent theme and a child theme which is currently activated.
Now i have a block where i need to remove the ::after
How i can remove it whithout having any issues with further theme updates?

```html
<div class="secondary-title">
  <div class="secondary-menu-toggle">
    <span class="et-icon et-burger"></span>
  </div>
    <span>Alle Kategorien</span>
    ::after
</div>
```

Comment: Is this snippet taken from *inspect element* or you actually see *::after* displayed in your code editor?

Comment: TY for answering, its from inspector.

Comment: You need to find CSS style for *secondary-title span::after* and change the content. It might be a different selector so change it accordingly. Should be similar to this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Comment: I was searching and I found it.
But in Wordpress i will need to do it with the Child Theme otherwise the new Update for the theme will overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add your own `css` in a child theme the below should remove the pseudo element:

```
.secondary-title::after {
  content: none;
}
```

or you can add `!important` for more specificity:

```
.secondary-title::after {
  content: none !important;
}
```